# Spring Tomcat 404 resource not found

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy an simple REST api with Spring inside a Tomcat installation, but all I'm getting are 404 resource not found when the war is deployed. It's running perfectly on localhost, but deploying is just not working. Tried every solution on stackoverflow, but almost all use configuration files instead of configuration annotations. This is my (important) code.

slember.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'

springBoot{
    executable = true
}

war {
    baseName = 'slember'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'slember'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.9.Final'
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.15.0-GA'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31'
    compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10"
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")


}
```

SlemberApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
        SlemberApplication.class
})
public class SlemberApplication {

    public static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SlemberApplication.class, args);
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);
        context.refresh();
    }
}
```

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.letscode.SlemberApplication
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SpringBootServletInitializer

Your code sample only shows a `main` method. When deploying as a WAR, the main isn't executed. You need to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

BTW, why do you use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to register AppConfig instead of letting Spring Boot picking it up ?
Either :

- `AppConfig` is in the same package (or below) of your `SlemberApplication`: it's loaded by default;
- move `SlemberApplication` so that it is higher (in the packages) than all your `@Configuration/@Component` classes (and then the previous point would apply);
- or you add `@ComponentScan` to specify `AppConfig`'s package.

#### You could use something like this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={AppConfig.class, SlemberApplication.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SlemberApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        super.configure(builder);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder().build().run(SlemberApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reasons why I'm getting 500 internal server error when making correct calls. It does warn me when I dont use proper requests (parameters ed)

Comment: Don't you have a stacktrace allong with this error ?